# Play Audio in JS

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I want to play an audio from javascript when loading the page without user action. In itself it is a playlist, and everything is loaded dynamically:

```
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
 /*
... etc
*/

selectTrack(index){
   audio.src = urls[index];
   audio.load();
   audio.play();
}


selectTrack(0); //Auto play
```

An example when calling selectTrack (0) for the first time:

```js
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
var track = 0;
var urls = [
  'https://themushroomkingdom.net/sounds/wav/smb3/smb3_level_clear.wav',
  'https://themushroomkingdom.net/sounds/wav/smb3/smb3_airship_clear.wav',
  'https://themushroomkingdom.net/sounds/wav/smb3/smb3_fortress_clear.wav',
];

function selectTrack(index) {
  audio.src = urls[index];
  audio.load();
  audio.play();
}

$("#next").click(function() {
  track = (++track >= urls.length) ? 0 : track;
  selectTrack(track);
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  track = (--track < 0) ? urls.length - 1 : track;
  selectTrack(track);
});

selectTrack(track);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="next">Next</button>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
```

Comment: What is the question? :)

Comment: the audio does not auto play, console launches an exception. XD

Comment: Please share a [mcve] that allows us to run and reproduce the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately you will need a user interaction to autoplay audio/video. (In most of the cases)

Comment: Have a read here, most modern browsers follow a similar approach. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/11/web-audio-autoplay